# Unlock BIOS config

Tags: cpu, bios, netbook, overclocking

I have ASUS x101h EEEPC and I want to overclock CPU, but BIOS clock settings are locked. Is there a way to unlock BIOS or update BIOS which have those options unlocked?

CPU is Intel Atom N435

Comment: Intel Atom N570 Processor

Comment: @Ramhound Why not? Now it works on 1.3GHz.

Comment: Sorry its Intel Atom N435 my mistake.

Comment: http://www.cpubenchmark.net/cpu.php?cpu=Intel+Atom+N435+%40+1.33GHz